# Accept Hosted Authorize Net Integration issue. No redirection to my localhost after payment

Tags: java, authorize.net

I am integrating Authorize net  for my website. I am able to generate Token. After getting token i am posting request  on my sandbox account. I am able to make test payment. But after making payment it does not return me back on my website. The Continue button does nothing.

Here is my settings and form request.  Please let me know if there is anything i am missing.
Here is my code for getting Token.

```
public static GetHostedPaymentPageResponse run(String apiLoginId, String transactionKey, Double amount) {
ApiOperationBase.setEnvironment(Environment.SANDBOX);
MerchantAuthenticationType merchantAuthenticationType  = new MerchantAuthenticationType() ;
merchantAuthenticationType.setName(apiLoginId);
merchantAuthenticationType.setTransactionKey(transactionKey);
ApiOperationBase.setMerchantAuthentication(merchantAuthenticationType);

// Create the payment transaction request
TransactionRequestType txnRequest = new TransactionRequestType();
txnRequest.setTransactionType(TransactionTypeEnum.AUTH_CAPTURE_TRANSACTION.value());
txnRequest.setAmount(new BigDecimal(amount).setScale(2, RoundingMode.CEILING));




 SettingType setting2 = new SettingType();
setting2.setSettingName("hostedPaymentOrderOptions");
setting2.setSettingValue("{\"show\": true}"); 
setting2.setSettingValue("{\"merchantName\": \"Questions Inc.\"}"); 

SettingType setting1 = new SettingType();
setting1.setSettingName("hostedPaymentButtonOptions");
setting1.setSettingValue("{\"text\": \"Pay Now\"}");


SettingType setting3 = new SettingType();
setting3.setSettingName("hostedPaymentReturnOptions");
setting3.setSettingValue("{\"showReceipt\": true}");
setting3.setSettingValue("{\"url\": \"http://localhost:8070/wap-adaptor/response.jsp\"}");
setting3.setSettingValue("{\"urlText\": \"Return\"}");
setting3.setSettingValue("{\"cancelUrl\": \"http://localhost:8070/wap-adaptor/response.jsp\"}");
setting3.setSettingValue("{\"cancelUrlText\": \"Cancel\"}");

ArrayOfSetting alist = new ArrayOfSetting();
alist.getSetting().add(setting1);
alist.getSetting().add(setting2);
alist.getSetting().add(setting3);

GetHostedPaymentPageRequest apiRequest = new GetHostedPaymentPageRequest();
apiRequest.setTransactionRequest(txnRequest);
apiRequest.setHostedPaymentSettings(alist);

GetHostedPaymentPageController controller = new GetHostedPaymentPageController(apiRequest);
controller.execute();

GetHostedPaymentPageResponse response = new GetHostedPaymentPageResponse();
```

Here is my request form

```
<form method="POST" action="https://test.authorize.net/payment/payment" id="DemoCheckoutForm" name="DemoCheckoutForm">
<input type="hidden" name="token" value="<%=token%>" >
<input type="submit" name="submit_b" value="Buy now" >
```

Answer (score 0):

Devender Kumar

Please, set your setting3 as below,

```
SettingType setting3 = new SettingType();
setting3.setSettingName("hostedPaymentReturnOptions");
setting3.setSettingValue("{\"showReceipt\": false}");
setting3.setSettingValue("{\"url\": \"http://localhost:8070/wap-adaptor/response.jsp\"}");
setting3.setSettingValue("{\"urlText\": \"Return\"}");
setting3.setSettingValue("{\"cancelUrl\": \"http://localhost:8070/wap-adaptor/response.jsp\"}");
setting3.setSettingValue("{\"cancelUrlText\": \"Cancel\"}");
```

showReceipt should be false when you want to redirect on given url in hostedPaymentReturnOptions setting.

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled across this page looking for a workaround. It looks like Authorize doesn't allow `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` in Cancel/Continue URLs. I'm still trying to figure out a way around.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the mistake I was doing.

```
SettingType setting3 = new SettingType();
setting3.setSettingName("hostedPaymentReturnOptions");
setting3.setSettingValue("{\"showReceipt\": true}");
setting3.setSettingValue("{\"url\": \"http://localhost:8070/wap-adaptor/response.jsp\"}");
setting3.setSettingValue("{\"urlText\": \"Return\"}");
setting3.setSettingValue("{\"cancelUrl\": \"http://localhost:8070/wap-adaptor/response.jsp\"}");
setting3.setSettingValue("{\"cancelUrlText\": \"Cancel\"}");
```

As you can see it will take the last value only.

```
setting3.setSettingValue("{\"cancelUrlText\": \"Cancel\"}");
```

Instead it should have been like below. Wrap all the parameter in json and then set the value.

```
setting3.setSettingValue("{\"showReceipt\": true,
\"url\": \"http://localhost:8070/wap-adaptor/response.jsp\",
\"urlText\": \"Return\",
\"cancelUrl\": \"http://localhost:8070/wap-adaptor/response.jsp\",
\"cancelUrlText\": \"Cancel\"}");
```

It was such a silly mistake.